# Show that the function $ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, f(x,y)=(2x,y)$ is $2-$bilipschitz.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Show that the function $ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2, f(x,y)=(2x,y)$ is $2-$bilipschitz.

I have that $f$ is $2-$bilipschitz if $$\frac12d(x,y) \le d(f(x),f(y)) \le 2d(x,y).$$ The metric seems to be the Euclidean metric so let $(x,y),(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Now $$\|f(x,y)-f(a,b)\|=\|(2x,y)-(2a,b)\| = \|(2(x,a),y-b)\|$$

but I cannot show get to the Lipschitz condition from here? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have that
$$
d(f(x,y),f(a,b))=||(2x,y)-(2a,b)||=(4(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2)^{1/2}\geq 
$$
$$
((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2)^{1/2}=d((x,y),(a,b))\geq d((x,y),(a,b))/2
$$
and
$$
(4(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2)^{1/2}\leq (4(x-a)^2+4(y-b)^2)^{1/2}= 2d((x,y),(a,b))
$$